# .Net 7 with MongoDB and Odata - ArgumentException: Value type of serializer is Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Container.AutoSelectedNamedProperty`

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, odata

I am using .Net 7 with MongoDB(2.20) and Odata(8.2.0). All filters like $filter working fine but when i tried using $select its giving this exception

Here is the exception:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH84W.png]

Its a very simple application having two classes - Customer and address
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Customer
{
public Customer()
{
Address = new List();
}

```
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("gender")]
    public string? Gender { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("address")]
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }

}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Address
{
    public Address()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
    }
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string? name { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("address")]
    public string? FullAddress { get; set; }
}
```

This is my program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.Configure<CustomerDatabaseSettings>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("CustomerDatabase"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomerService>();
var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || type.FullName.StartsWith("Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmModel") || type.FullName.StartsWith("TestMongoOData.Models"));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
// Add services to the container.


var edmModel = EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddOData(options =>
    options.Select().Filter().Count().OrderBy().Expand().AddRouteComponents(edmModel));
```

i dont know what i am doing wrong. any help would be greatly appreciated